# Back Button behaviour after Post-Redirect-Get

Tags: http, jsf, post-redirect-get

My application disables caching on the browser via responses headers and then uses the Post-Redirect-Get pattern to enable the back button to "re-Get" the current page.
However on retesting this now with Firefox 12 and IE 8 I'm not seeing the results I was expecting (or that I had seen before with IE 6).

Upon selecting the back button I can see that the browser is attempting to perform the original request (the Post), not the redirected request (the Get). When I look at the requests on the network tab of Firebug I see the following:

[image: Post-Redirect-Get]

Looks like the browser is treating the Post and Get as the same request and hence selecting the back button is re-submitting the Post:

[image: Result of Back Button]

I am using JSF, but I think this is a browser issue.  Does anyone know why the browser is not performing a get of the redirected page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's working fine. The back button re-executes the request **before** "POST accountDetails.xhtml" which is not listed in your 1st screenshot, but is according the 2nd screenshot apparently (and logically) a "GET accountDetails.xhtml". You're apparently in the bean associated with that view or in some filter doing some checks and redirecting to "registrationWelcome.xhtml". The "POST accountDetails.xhtml" in the 1st screenshot is the **current** request which has been redirected to "reviewInfo.xhtml".

The back button does not re-execute the redirect. It's your own code which did it. The back button does also not re-execute the POST request, which is confirmed in the 2nd screenshot.

Comment: Thank you BalusC, You are correct, the request that precedes the "POST accountDetails.xhtml" is a "Get accountDetails.xhtml".  Just to clarify my understanding, you are saying that the back button considers the "POST accountDetails.xhtml -> GET reviewInfo.xhtml" as the same request (and the current request) and therefore the previous request "GET accountDetails.xhtml" is executed by the back button?

Comment: The back button will only re-execute `GET reviewInfo.xhtml` instead of `POST accountDetails.xhtml` when the back button is pressed in the next page *after* you navigated away from `reviewInfo.xhtml`. The back button really doesn't re-execute the current request. The refresh button does that. Without the PRG, the refresh button would by the way have re-executed the POST.

Comment: Did you mean "Without the PRG, the **back** button would by the way have re-executed the POST."?

Comment: Yes that also, but only when you're currently in the page *after* the POST request. The redirected request doesn't count as "after the POST". It has entirely replaced the POST in browser's history.