# Prevent user from going back to login form after logging-in and session pages after logging-out?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, servlet-filters

I am developing an application in Java which requires user to log in and out. I want to PREVENT the user from going back to:

1. Login page after logging in
2. Session pages after logging out

I have looked at some questions on StackOverflow that answer these problems separately and I do not know whether to implement separate filters for both of them or not?

Also, should I use session checking or non-caching of session pages or both?

Can someone provide a sample of code for this problem?

Thank You

Comment: _I do not know whether to implement separate filters for both of them or not?_ **First implement and see if you face any problems post that.**

Answer (score 0):

Redirect after post technique can prevent going back in the browser.
Remember that is only client side browser visual effect and not a security feature to avoid users going back to secured pages!

links:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/java/design-patterns/post-redirect-get-prg-pattern-in-servlet-jsp/

[Back Button behaviour after Post-Redirect-Get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10837981/back-button-behaviour-after-post-redirect-get)

Answer (score 0):

I used this code finally and seemed to work well.

```
public class SessionFilter implements Filter {

/**
 * Default constructor.
 */
public SessionFilter() {
}

/**
 * @see Filter#destroy()
 */
public void destroy() {
}

/**
 * @see Filter#doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain)
 */
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest hRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    HttpServletResponse hResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
    HttpSession session = hRequest.getSession(false); // returns existing or
                                                        // null

    if (session == null || session.getAttribute("user_email") == null) {
        hResponse.sendRedirect(hRequest.getContextPath() + "/login.jsp");
        // return;
    } else {
        hResponse.setHeader("Cache-Control",
                "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
        hResponse.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
        hResponse.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }


}

/**
 * @see Filter#init(FilterConfig)
 */
public void init(FilterConfig fConfig) throws ServletException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
```

}